# Unable to set timezone in a Dockerfile for a Windows container

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am new to dockerfile in Azure Devops.
I am currently writing a dockerfile in which I need to set the timezone.
Based on this dockerfile, I need an image to be created which already has the correct timezone. I used several attempts, but it keeps failing.
I tried tzutil also, but it's not recognized during the creation of the image.

The image is being built by Azure DevOps agents.

```
# Base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime
```

In my last attempt I tried to set the timezone like this.

`RUN powershell -Command Set-TimeZone -Name "W. Europe Standard Time"`

But if failed with the following exception

```
Set-TimeZone : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Eu
rope'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-TimeZone -Name W. Europe Standard Time1.
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-TimeZone], ParameterBi 
   ndingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
   .Commands.SetTimeZoneCommand
```

Can anyone help me setting the timezone for this image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I got this working with the following steps.
First I create a powershell script that looks like this

```
Write-Host "set W. Europe Standard Time"
tzutil /s "W. Europe Standard Time"

Write-Host "Starting IIS"
C:\LogMonitor\LogMonitor.exe C:\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc
```

Next I tell the docker container not automatically startup IIS.
I configure the Dockerfile to copy the Powershell script (see above) to the container.
At the end of the dockerfile I startup the powershell script, which sets the timezone and will startup IIS

```
# Base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force;"]

# Disable IIS auto start
RUN ["cmd", "/S", "/C", "sc", "config", "w3svc", "start=demand"]

# Copy powershell script to change 
RUN md c:\aspnet-startup
COPY ContainerFiles/. c:/aspnet-startup

#DO SOME OTHER STUFF THAT YOU NEED TO DO


#Now start IIS with that script, which also sets the timezone
ENTRYPOINT [ "powershell.exe", "c:\\aspnet-startup\\start.ps1" ]
```